# AutoLayout or not? How to position 3 subviews?

Tags: ios, positioning, autolayout, subview

I can't figure out how to correctly position subviews in a Navigation Controller.
I am trying to position a view, table and another view.

[image]

If I turn off AutoLayout than top view and table are ok but my bottom view is pushed off the screen.
With autolayout I get both the table and bottom view in the wrong place:

[image]

I try to set frame in viewDidLoad as follows (calendarPicker is position at the top below navigation bar), I want the configPanel to be on the bottom, I hide bottom bar on Push.

```
self.eventsTable.frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.calendarPicker.frame),
                                    self.eventsTable.bounds.size.width,
                                    self.view.bounds.size.height - self.calendarPicker.bounds.size.height
                                    );
self.configPanel.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height,
                                    self.configPanel.bounds.size.width,
                                    self.view.bounds.size.height - self.configPanel.bounds.size.height
                                    );
```

Should I rely on autolayout? How should I make my constraints?
I believe my problems arise due to autosizing of the table mostly, but given that I am setting its frame size why would it not change? I do not want to remove auto layout since it is used on other views designed in the storyboard and from what I understand it applies to all?
Is there something that I am missing that needs to be done on top of setting the frames of individual controls?

**EDIT:**
I think my biggest problem is autolayout and inability to size table appropriately. If I add constraint to the bottom view to be 0 from bottom of the view, it will originally appear correctly. However consequently when resizing table and top view, the table will push bottom view down sizing itself to occupy all available space.
I need to force UITableView to be no more than height between the bottom of the top view and lower view, but still not sure how to do this. 
**Somewhat closer**
Removing code for frame change of the table fixes the issue of the bottom view being pushed off. However in this case top view overlapps table when it changes size at the same time not being drawn correctly:
[image]

Comment: uncheck autolayout(which you have already done I guess), and then use auto-sizing for all your views. Autosizing is available in xcode in the right-hand panel of properties- in size inspector. Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: I assume you mean Autoresize Subviews on the container view? If so it is already done and it still does not work.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand how it should work, but if non of the answers actually helped should I still accept them? If you take a look on most of them there are no answers at all. Nothing that has been said here got me any closer to resolving the issue unfortunately. Before actually implying something maybe you should have looked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck autolayout and then set frames of all three subviews. 
Or
If you want constraints then you can use NSLayoutConstraint class to add constraint to your subviews.

Comment: NSLayoutConstraint and setting them programmatically may be the correct answer, but so far I was not able to get it to work. I found this http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2014/02/resize-uitableview-height-with-auto-layout/. I added height constraint, then vertical space constraint to bottom layout guide. Still trying to get it to work, but little progress.

Comment: Accepting this as it seems this is as close to my problem solution as I can get. Using article I pointed out, allows movement and height adjustment of the table. Still do not have it working but think with more constraints it would be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against switching off autolayout, especially because you can't do it on a view by view basis. Autolayout is a must if you tend to do i18n or want to make sure your app does well in different screen resolutions/orientation.

Comment: I agree turning it off is not a good idea for many other reasons as well. Plus it does not resolve the issue anyway, it just delays it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This!
disable use Autolayout in storyboard. Place your three views on view controller(view1, view2, view3). Next go to size inspector and use autosizing masks for all three views. Check this, which will help you
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1